# What is the dif between mac and windows about android SDK

Tags: android, windows, macos, sdk

as the question stated. I am planning to copy android SDK library from my microsoft windows pc to my new Mac PC. Should I download the mac version of sdk or copying the directory from windows to mac is enough ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SDK (Java part) is identical, but the NDK (which may also be called a part of the SDK) contains prebuilt Windows/Linux/Mac versions of the GCC compiler to produce ARM/MIPS/x86 Android executables.

To compile native native code on Mac you need different prebuilt GCC toolchain (included in NDK). That part certainly cannot be copied from Windows.

To build Java just make sure your Mac is not too old (like PowerPC) and support the Android SDK and official JDK to run Ant build scripts.

The direct copying may have one problem: the CLASSPATH variable will point to your old Windows paths, not the Mac paths.

Answer (score 5):

There's no big difference, but you will need to download the SDK again. This is because not everything is Java, some of it is native code and won't work on your Mac coming from Windows. But functionally, it's identical.

Comment: what about the executable files in windows?  *I don't think that will work in mac OS*