# Android SDK From Windows To Mac

Tags: android, android-studio

I had download Android SDK (18 GB) in android studio on windows , now I bought new mac and I would like copy the sdk from window to mac.

is it possible to copy the sdk from windows to mac ?

or

what can I copy from sdk to work on the mac ?

Comment: I think this should awnser your question:
[What is the dif between mac and windows about android SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866241/what-is-the-dif-between-mac-and-windows-about-android-sdk)

Answer (score 2):

You would have to download it again on your mac as some of it is native code won't work on your Mac.